# Cannot open source file "sys/types.h" , "sys/stat.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I just updated it and started to get this error on every project I have:

> C++ cannot open source file "sys/types.h"
>   C++ cannot open source file "sys/stat.h"

Didn't find any similar questions so sorry if duplicated. The error is for this 2 lines in file **wchar.h** and the error code is **E1969** for both errors, tried repairing but didn't work, any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

Comment: Because those headers aren't standard.

Comment: Check that the files exist.  The typical install path for a recent VS2017 version is C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\sys.  Next check Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hum, so VS _does_ ship versions of these headers?

Comment: Of course, these #includes from compiler .h files don't fall from the sky.

Comment: @HansPassant: Nobody's told me about any compiler .h files. No need for the snark. I look forward to reading your answer!

Comment: @HansPassant OH there's no sys file in \ucrt\

Comment: @Hanspassant Well technically they do fall from the sky. The cloud rather.

Comment: Consider installing some Linux distribution on your computer. Then you could compile that code on your Linux system (since your code uses POSIX features).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch uhh How do i disable POSIX features?

Comment: **You rewrite your code** for your operating system and API. You could dive into  [WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation if you want to target Windows. You could choose some cross-plateform toolkit or framework such as [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch dude i don't even use Linux, it's not just one project its every project i have has this error, even if i make a new project i get this error, do i just make the 2 include a comment "//#include" so they don't give me an error? whatsoever im really new to C++ anyway lol

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error when I opened a project made by someone else in an older version of Visual Studio. Here is how I solved it:

Go to Project > [Project name] Properties...

Click VC++ Directories

Select Include Directories then Click the drop-down arrow to the right and select Edit...

Click New Line icon (looks like new folder icon)

Click the ... to browse for a directory

Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt
(Note that you don't drill down into the sys folder)

Click Select Folder > Ok > Ok

Once I did that the error was gone along with related errors in the code.

Answer (score 3):

With Visual Studio 2019 CE the path is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the latest version of VS2017 Community installed, and those headers are now located here:
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\SDK\include\ucrt\sys

```
2017-11-21  07:50 PM    <DIR>          .
2017-11-21  07:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
2017-11-21  04:59 PM               609 locking.h
2017-11-21  04:59 PM             6,615 stat.h
2017-11-21  04:59 PM             2,446 timeb.h
2017-11-21  04:59 PM               740 types.h
2017-11-21  04:59 PM             4,643 utime.h
```

Update the path references, or reinstall the SDK if the references are not in your own code.  This is part of MS's great Universal CRT refactoring. See here, for example:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with `#include <sys/types.h>` which I was able to resolve by enabling the "Inherit from parent or project defaults" button on the `Property Pages/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Include Directories/<DropDown>/<Edit...>` dialog.  This had been cleared somehow.

This causes the following paths to be added:

```
$(VC_IncludePath)
$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)
```

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017 version 15.9.18